# Suppress the page number on a specific page

Tags: header-footer

**Problem description**: I have 2 images that I'd like them to be in the same page. The problem is that I can't scale their size down and therefore the 2nd one overlaps with the page number.

**Question 1**: Is there a way to tell `XeLatex` not to display the page number of **a particular page** (not for all the pages)? If I try to move the page number to the right footer or right header (with `fancyhdr`), then it overlaps with text the text in some other page.

**Question 2**: Is there any other, more clean, way to fit those images in the same page *and* keep the page number as well?

[image]

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: Can you please show a minimal working example that reproduces the undesired behaviour? Maybe there is another workaround than bypassing the page-numbering...

Comment: Could it be, that the figure is just too big for the page and sticks down in the margin/foot? Then i guess removing the pagenumber isn't the best idea.

Comment: @Johannes_B yeh, that's it. I have 2 images in the same page (the screenshot shows the 2nd one), and I'd like them to be on the same page. And scaling them down isn't an option. Hm.

Comment: Can you construct a minimal example that lets us reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: @HarishKumar Can you make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the page number from just one page, the easiest way is to add `\thispagestyle{empty}` in the proper position (somewhere in that page). This will remove headers too.

On the other hand, you may use `\resizebox` from `graphicx` package, `height` option to `\includegraphics` with proper value, or use `adjustbox` package for limiting the size of the picture within the page. No code is provided in the absence of MWE. Please try these suggestions and if stuck, either drop a comment or ask a new question.