# How can I modify Header of a particular page?

Tags: header-footer

I am writing my thesis and on the abstract page, a header "CONTENT" is coming. I want to remove the header from that particular page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE (code sample showing your problem) to help us help you.

Comment: Related: [Suppress the page number on a specific page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169241/suppress-the-page-number-on-a-specific-page)

Answer (score 2):

If you want no header or footer use `\pagestyle{empty}`. After that page set it back to `\pagestyle{fancy}` or whatever you would like to have.

**EDIT:** better: If you want no header or footer on *just one page* use `\thispagestyle{empty}`. It is reset automatically after that page.

If you want to remove the header but keep a footer you can define a custom pagestyle:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% ----- header & footer -----
\newcommand{\header}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[c]{CONTENT}
}
\newcommand{\footer}{
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}%
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[r]{page~\thepage}
}

\newcommand{\noheader}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhead{}
}
\newcommand{\nofooter}{
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyfoot{}
}


% ----- pagestyles -----
% pagestyle fancy
\header
\footer

% custom pagestyle
\fancypagestyle{abstract}{%
    \noheader%
    \footer%
}

% ----- set default pagestyle -----
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Use the custom pagestyle with `\thispagestyle{abstract}`.