# my header has a file number which needs to change every few pages

Tags: header

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{letter}                 %noting sheet /vertical line template
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                     %for color of table
%\usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
%\usepackage{multirow} % Required for multirows
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
 \usepackage{indentfirst}
 \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
% \usepackage{datetime2}
 \usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}            %footnotes will have symbols instead of                                                                        numbers
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}             %best
\usepackage[
  height=8in,      % height of the text block
  width=5.1in,       % width of the text block
  top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
  headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
  headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
  heightrounded,   % ensure an integer number of lines
%  showframe,       % show the main blocks
  verbose,         % show the values of the parameters in the log file
]{geometry}
%header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\newcommand{\footer}{                               %change the header or footer on a particular page
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[c]{CONTENT}
    \fancyfoot[L]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 Typeset in \LaTeX}}

\fancyhead[R]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 Special Assignment Wing\\Controllerate of Quality Assurance \\ Armoured Vehicle                                Electronics\\Avadi, Chennai – 600 054}

\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../images/"dgqa logo".png} }
\fancyhead[L]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 File No: 20211/JC/SA dt 17 Sep 2019}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 Typeset in \LaTeX}


\begin{document}

                \begin{center}
                    \underline{NOTING SHEET}                    \\
                    \underline{dfas}    \\
                \end{center}

\underline{Jt Controller (SA)/MR}

\begin{enumerate}
    nd are also enclosed \footnote{Flag 5A}.The copy of typeset                 source code used for printout of the Manual is enclosed for perusal also \footnote{Flag 6A}.

    \item Placed for perusal please..
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1cm}
                                            \raggedleft {(JS Bibra)}\\




\pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   \thispagestyle{empty}
%   \footer     
                \begin{center}
                    \underline{NOTING SHEET}                    \\
                    \underline{hjljkll} \\
                \end{center}

\underline{Jt Controller (SA)/MR}\\ 
\DTMlangsetup{showdayofmonth=false}
 \hspace{1em}12 \today

\begin{enumerate}
    \item ownloaded from the Internet for           study of the typesetting language and are also enclosed \footnote{Flag 5A}.The copy of typeset              source code used for printout of the Manual is enclosed for perusal also \footnote{Flag 6A}.

\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1cm}
%\smallskip
%\medskip
%\bigskip                                       
                                                        \raggedleft {(JS Bibra)}\\



\pagebreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\fancyhead[L]{}
\begin{center}
                    \underline{NOTING SHEET}                    \\
                    \underline{klklkjljk}   \\
                \end{center}

\underline{Reviewing Officer}\\
            {%
            \footnotesize 
                 File No: 48332/StandingOrders/2019/1 \\dt 02 Jul 2019}

\begin{enumerate}


\item Placed for perusal please.
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1cm}
%\smallskip
%\medskip
%\bigskip                                       
                                                        \raggedleft {(JS Bibra)}\\

\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365238/197451

Comment: Could you be more precise? When do you need the header to change? Every X pages? Something else?

Comment: i have made a template for a letter/memo-- everyday there is anew memo for a different project number/case number --so the header with the project number will need to be changed every day--but this would change the header of the previous day also--the other solution is off course change the project number to the main content of the letter and out of the header--any solution?

Comment: So essentially, you want your header to change to include some definition provided in an included file? In a similar way to how the header in a book contains the name of the chapter that is currently being rendered?

Comment: the project number is to be changed  in the header of the memo on a daily basis as per the updates received from the ground staff--so today the header would pertain to project x tomorrow project y and so on

Comment: Can you please give an example in your post how you want your document to look like? It is really not clear to me if this is a huge document containing all the memos, or only one document per memo, or something else.

Comment: Can you make the posted document so, that it is compilable? No external references and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Every time the file number is changed, mark it.  Then, in the header, use `\firstmark`.

Comment: @barbara--a little more detail please--how to ??