# How to use custom page style on a single page and another for all subsequent pages?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

Using the `scrbook` class of KOMA script I created two distinc page styles named `StyleA` and `StyleB` via the `\newpagestyle` command. I'd like to apply the first style to a single page. If the content of the page I applied `StyleA` to, spans over multiple pages, the second style should be used by all subsequent pages. However, I don't know the size of the content in adavance.

How do I implement this behavior using KOMA script?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example showing the problem.

Comment: Maybe related: [Suppress the page number on a specific page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169241/suppress-the-page-number-on-a-specific-page) or [How can I modify Header of a particular page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365236/how-can-i-modify-header-of-a-particular-page)

Comment: Or [How I can typeset a footer on only one page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220800/how-i-can-typeset-a-footer-on-only-one-page)

Answer (score 8):

`\thispagestyle{StyleA}` sets the page style only for the current page. On the next page the style set by `\pagestyle` will be used again.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newpagestyle{StyleA}{{StyleA left page}{StyleA right page}{Style A onesided document}}{{}{}{}}
\newpagestyle{StyleB}{{StyleB left page}{StyleB right page}{Style A onesided document}}{{}{}{}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{StyleB}% use StyeleB for the document
\lipsum[1-15]
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{StyleA}% use StyleA only for this page
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]