# Different pagestyles for different chapters

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I found this great example in an answer of this question [How to use custom page style on a single page and another for all subsequent pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386185/48696) and changed it a little bit.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newpagestyle{StyleA}{{StyleA left page}{StyleA right page}{Style A onesided document}}{{}{}{}}
\newpagestyle{StyleB}{{StyleB left page}{StyleB right page}{Style A onesided document}}{{}{}{}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{StyleB}% use StyeleB for the document
\chapter{chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter{chapter 2}
\pagestyle{StyleA}% use StyleA only for this page
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{special chapter}
\lipsum[16-30]
\pagestyle{StyleB}% use StyleB for the document
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Kapitel 3}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

This works quite good for me since I only want to change the headers for my chapters.

But there are some questions I could not find an answer to so I ask them here.

1. How can I define the left, center and right part of the header or footer? I normally use `\ohead{}`, `\chead{}`, `\ihead{}`, etc.
2. Is it possible to add these created styles so that they also will be used for the first page of the chapter? Using `\chapterpagestyle{StyleA}` is not working.
3. I have created my own section command with `\DeclareNewSectionCommand{}`. Is it possible to automate it in a way, that the `\pagestyle{StyleB}`-command is added automatically to the normal chapter-command `\chapter{}`, so that the usage of it resets the changed pagestyle to StyleB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `\ohead` etc. to define the parts of header and footer, then use `\newpairofpagestyles` for the definition of your new page styles. Then you get pairs of pagestyles, eg. `StyleA` as main pagestyle and `plain.StyleA` as associated plain style.

Note that `plain` is only an alias for the plain style of the active "pair of pagestyles".

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% note the *: same content for plain.scrheadings and scrheadings
\chead*{\currentpagestyle}% show the used page style

\newpairofpagestyles
  [scrheadings]% scrheadings as parent style -> clone its *current* settings
  {StyleA}% name of the new layer page style
  {
    \ohead*{StyleA outer head}% note the *: same content for plain.StyleA and StyleA
    \ihead*{StyleA inner head}%
  }% definitions for the new page style
\newpairofpagestyles
  [scrheadings]
  {StyleB}
  {
    \ohead{StyleB outer head}%
    \ihead{StyleB inner head}%
  }

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{StyleB}}{}{\PatchFailed}% reset the page style for \chapter

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{StyleB}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage Test
\chapter{chapter 1}
\chapter{chapter 2}
\chapter{special chapter}
\pagestyle{StyleA}
\lipsum[16-30]
\chapter{Kapitel 3}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Additional remark: By default the style of chapter pages is `plain`. This can be changed by redefinition of `\chapterpagestyle`: `\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{<page style name>}`. But in the example above there was no redefinition needed because `\pagestyle{StyleA}` yields to `plain` as alias of `plain.StyleA` and `\pagestyle{StyleB}` yields to `plain` as alias of `plain.StyleB`.